# The custom logo, site title, and description doesn't appear at the same time

Tags: php, code

The problem I'm having is the custom logo, site title, and description won't appear at the same time. In image 1 below, you can see that with no custom logo, the site title, and description appears just fine.

```php
<div id="hotwp-logo">
    <?php if ( has_custom_logo() ) : ?>
        <div class="site-branding">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="hotwp-logo-img-link">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( hotwp_custom_logo() ); ?>" alt="" class="hotwp-logo-img"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="hotwp-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <p class="hotwp-site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!--/#hotwp-logo -->
```

**When I don’t have a logo, the tag line and the description is shown.**

**Image 1** [image: Image 1]

**When I add a custom logo, the tag line and the description disappears.**

**Image 2** [image: Image 2 @]

**This was edited to show what I need. The tag line and the description need to show, shifting to the right of the logo.**

**Image 3** [image: Image 3]

Comment: probably your problem is not "with logo" but with "logo in the wp theme" and you shoul analyse .PHP file (usually header.php) not the resulting HTML (see Jim Worall answer)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but it looks like you have an if-else.  If there is a logo, it shows.  Else the title and description show.  Try removing the if-else stuff.

Comment: <?php
      if ( has_custom_logo() ) {
       the_custom_logo();
      } else {
...

Answer (score 2):

Ricky, you'll have to write the proper CSS to get it to display exactly as you want it to, but the problem you're having is that you're ONLY requesting the custom logo IF the custom logo exists.  IF it doesn't exist, you're asking for the title and the description, but ONLY if there is no logo.

Try this instead:

```
<div id="hotwp-logo">
<?php if( has_custom_logo() ) : ?>
    <div class="site-branding">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home" class="hotwp-logo-img-link">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( hotwp_custom_logo() ); ?>" alt="" class="hotwp-logo-img"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="title-container">
            <h1 class="hotwp-site-title">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <p class="hotwp-site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="site-branding no-logo">
        <div class="title-container">
            <h1 class="hotwp-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <p class="hotwp-site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To make things a bit easier for styling purposes I wrapped the logo in a `<div>` with the class `logo-container` and did the same for the title and description - that'll just make it a bit easier for you to position them using CSS, but if you can remove those extra divs if you feel they're overkill.  I also added a `no-logo` class to the `site-branding` div for the instance where there isn't a logo so you can modify the styling there.

**EDITED | added some CSS:**

```
.site-branding{
     display:flex;
     align-items:center;
     justify-content:flex-start;
     flex-direction:row;
     width:100%;
}
.logo-container{
     width:35%;
}
.title-container{
     width:65%;
     display:flex;
     align-items:flex-start;
     justify-content:flex-start;
     flex-direction:column;
}
.title-container > .hotwp-site-title,
.title-container > .hotwp-site-description{
     display:block;
     width:100%;
}
```

*Haven't tested the CSS but that's the general idea.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked. However, you were so right about the css. When I tried to float left with the title and the description, they ended up under the logo. I tried other positions and was worst. Leaving it a loan, the title ends up in the middle of the page and below the container of the logo. The description stays under the logo. Here's the css script for the logo.

Comment: Ricky, I added some CSS but haven't tested it out so it may need some massaging.  If my answer addresses the main part of your question please make sure you accept it as the answer.  If you need more complex CSS help you'll probably be better off asking it as a separate question.

Comment: Thank You Tony. Your code did work. It wasn't working so well at first. So I played around with the logo and the title container width. I change the logo container from 35% to 0% and the title container from 65% to 42% and it lined up perfectly. So, thank you again.

Comment: Tony, just noticed the flag on your comment above. I see nothing wrong with your comment. Have no idea why someone flagged your comment.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tony.
This is the css code I have. May be this will help. I tried to ad it to my comment yesterday, but it wouldn't let me.

```
#hotwp-logo{
margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
float:left;
width:41%;
```

}
.hotwp-logo-img-link{
display:block;
}
.hotwp-logo-img{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.hotwp-site-title{
font:normal bold 24px 'Playfair Display',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
margin:0 0 15px 0 !important;
line-height:1 !important;
color:#333333;
}
.hotwp-site-title a{
color:#333333;
text-decoration:none;
}
.hotwp-site-description{
font:normal normal 13px Domine,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
line-height:1 !important;
color:#333333;
}
.hotwp-header-banner #hotwp-logo{
width:41%;
}
.hotwp-header-search #hotwp-logo{
width:71%;
}
.hotwp-header-full #hotwp-logo{
margin:5px 0px 10px 0px;
float:none;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
.hotwp-header-full .hotwp-logo-img{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
}
#hotwp-logo{
margin:5px 0px 10px 0px;
float:none;
width:100% !important;
text-align:center;
}
.hotwp-logo-img{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin:0 auto;
}